# How to get notification for any application launched

Tags: compact-framework

i am working on an application for windows mobile 6.5, which need to know whenever any application is launched.
Is there any way to get notified when any application is launched?

Can we do something like this?

[ManagementEventWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementeventwatcher%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to get an event when a new process is created. However, you can get a list of processes using the ToolHelp API, so it should be possible to get the necessary information, but you need to continuously poll in order to detect when a process is started.

Access to the ToolHelp API is not provided in compact framework but you can use the native API instead. An example can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446560.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to have to poll for the available processes using Allan's suggestion.  I've worked on custom Windows CE shells, and they use the RegisterTaskBar(HWND) to receive notification when windows are created, raised, and destroyed.  But that doesn't means every process has a window.